# rails active admin: how to present a table as read only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I let admins do a lot of administration of the web site with the wonderful active admin gem.

I have a table called Audit Trail, I want to show the admins this table but obviously it shouldn't be tampered with.

Does active admin support a concept of "read only" tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your `admin/yourmodel.rb` file will only allow `index` and `show` actions, which is similar to "read only":

```
actions :index, :show
```